# Why is Google Now Launcher using Samsung Theme Store Icons although the theme is uninstalled?

Tags: samsung, google-now, themes

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 5.1.1. I installed Google Now Launcher then I installed a theme from Samsung theme store, which replaced the default icons. After removing the theme and the launcher, I came back to Google Now, and although the theme was removed, the same Icons remain, even with default theme. Tried countless reinstalls of Google now launcher, but still no results.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Examples]

Comment: The S Planner icons are different in the two screenshots.

Comment: Because those apps are made by Samsung and retain the logos Samsung picks for them even when using a different launcher (even Google's!).

Answer (score 2):

Fyi for anyone googling this or looking for this still. I had my s7 edge display scaling set to condensed to fit more on the screen. Once I changed it back to standard (with the material Samsung theme applied) and rebooted the correct icons appeared. Could be that the change forces the launcher to recreate icons or clear it's cache etc.

Also, stock android lovers, install good lock from the galaxy app stores to bring the stock android notification shade and status bar into your s7. Got a very stock feel now with Samsung material theme, Google now launcher and good lock.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Changing the display scaling worked for me. Bizarre! Thanks a ton for posting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my Galaxy S7. It's a compatibility issue with using the 3rd party launcher. If I do a soft reset (vol down + power key) some of the icons will reset (the phone, contacts, and some of my apps).  The only ways I have found of changing all the icons back to the default is by doing a factory reset. I have spoken with Samsung support and it doesn't sound like there is any willingness to correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it I had same problem! Search apps.. find Google now launcher app on your phone. (I forgot i downloaded it) click it, then choose TouchWiz, bam fixed. 
My icons were also messed up when trying to switch back to default theme they wouldn't switch back to the default icons so the way I did that was find easy mode, apply easy mode under "personal" in settings, go back again after applying easy mode and apply standard mode. All icons will be restored to default.

Answer (score 0):

Google App seems to cache the icons used when first setting it up. Go to Settings-Apps, find it and clear launcher data. It will reset your homescreen layout but will not mess with other Google data such as search preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings >
           Applications >
           Application Manager>
           Go to Google App>
          Storage>
          Manage Storage>
          Clear Launcher Data

This will reset the GNL.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to change screen resolution

> Settings > display > screen resolution

Then change it back again.

No need to change launcher or restart or anything.

Note: You must go back to the home screen before changing it back.